# Is the inner product $f: H\times H \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ for a Hilbert space, $H$, continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

I know that the inner product above is continuous in each coordinates (provable by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality). I also know that continuity in each coordinate (i.e. $f_v:H \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is continuous) does not determine continuity of the function $f$.

I believe this would require me to define a norm on the product space but I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Continuity is meant in terms of the product topology, which incidentally can be normed with the natural inner product $\langle (x,y);(v,w)\rangle_{H_1\times H_2}=\langle x;v\rangle_{H_1}+\langle y;w\rangle_{H_2}$. However, while convenient, it isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: It is continuous as a two-variable function and can also be proven with the CS inequality

Comment: How did you use the CS inequality to prove that $f$ is continuous in a single coordinate? Try to set up the proof that $f$ is continuos, and see that it works more or less exactly the same. You have to juggle a few more terms, but that's about it.

Comment: $|(x,y)-(a,b)|=|(x,y)-(x,b)+(x,b)-(a,b)|\leq|(x,y-b)|+|(x-a,b)|\leq\|x\|\|y-b\|+\|b\|\|(x-a)\|$. This in turn is bounded by $\|x\|\|y-b\|+(\|y-b\|+\|y\|)\|(x-a)\|$. If $x,y$ are fixed and $a$ is close to $x$ and $b$ is close to $y$, then this bound is small.